# Exception in spring bean creation coming from Inetutilsproperties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix

Please help me with the below exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.commons.util.InetUtilsProperties#3311b9b9': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'SPRING_UTIL_TIMEOUT_SEC:1' in value "spring.util.timeout.sec:${SPRING_UTIL_TIMEOUT_SEC:1}"
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1268)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
```

Spring some how is not able to parse the SPRING_UTIL_TIMEOUT_SEC:1.

Comment: Share your code. It is really hard to find a problem without it, cause we don't see any problems right now (only stacktrace, which says nothing about your implementation/code).

Comment: Sorry @MattIT for not providing the source code . I am using a third party library and the exception is coming from there.  All i have been able to pin point so far is that this "SPRING_UTIL_TIMEOUT_SEC:1" is inside the  spring class  https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/spring-cloud-commons/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/commons/util/InetUtilsProperties.java not sure how to resolve. sorry for any inconvenience.